# Can we move RMQ messages in batches to another RMQ using shovel(dynamic)?

Tags: rabbitmq, rmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I wrote a script which uses RMQ shovel's PUT api to move messages to another RMQ but I was wondering about how it works internally. Does it move all the messages instantaneously? If yes, can we move it in batches for optimising it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html):

> A shovel behaves like a well-written client application, which connects to its source and destination, consumes and republishes messages, and uses acknowledgements on both ends to cope with failures.

> What Does a Shovel Do?
> In essence, a shovel is a minimalistic message pump. Each shovel:
>
> - Connects to the source and destination clusters
> - Consumes messages from a queue
> - Re-publishes to a destination
> - Uses data safety features on both ends and handles failures

Rabbitmq publishers can handle batch of messages depending on your acknowledgement strategy (see [Publisher Acknowledgements and Data Safety](https://www.rabbitmq.com/publishers.html#data-safety)).

If you want more control on the publisher behaviour, you should create your own and not use the shovel plugin.